# Android inflating errors on some devices that causes force close

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-inflate

I was developing an android app and I have tested this app on Android 7, Its working well. But at the end I decided to test it on lower versions and was surprised.
I'm getting many inflating errors while starting some activities.
here is my app gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "x.x.x"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 0
        versionName "x"
        testInstrumentationRunner  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
    implementation 'br.com.simplepass:loading-button-android:1.14.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.traex.expandablelayout:library:1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.markomilos:paginate:0.5.1'
    implementation 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
}
```

here is just a small piece of logcat errors :

```
Process: com.x.x, PID: 8878
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.x.x/com.x.x.Tickets}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #97: Binary XML file line #97: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2421)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5440)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #97: Binary XML file line #97: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.x.x.Tickets.onCreate(Tickets.java:51)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2374)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5440) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #97: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.x.x.Tickets.onCreate(Tickets.java:51) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2374) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5440) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.x.x.Tickets.onCreate(Tickets.java:51) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2374) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5440) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable()' on a null object reference
    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable$ChildDrawable.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:1723)
    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable$LayerState.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:1792)
    at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable$RippleState.<init>(RippleDrawable.java:998)
    at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.createConstantState(RippleDrawable.java:989)
    at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.createConstantState(RippleDrawable.java:96)
    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.mutate(LayerDrawable.java:1652)
    at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.mutate(RippleDrawable.java:975)
    at android.view.View.applyBackgroundTint(View.java:17430)
    at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:17306)
    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.access$001(FloatingActionButton.java:69)
    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$ShadowDelegateImpl.setBackgroundDrawable(FloatingActionButton.java:862)
    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButtonLollipop.setBackgroundDrawable(FloatingActionButtonLollipop.java:73)
    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:188)
    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.j
```

this project works fine on android 7 but I get these errors on android 4.2.2 and 6.0.1 (maybe other devices too)

here is my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:expandable="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Tickets">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/ticketsAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/ticketsDashboard_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <include android:id="@+id/ticketsBar" layout="@layout/others_toolbar"></include>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/tickets_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <fr.castorflex.android.smoothprogressbar.SmoothProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/load_more_progressbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:spb_color="@color/dark_primary"
        app:spb_mirror_mode="true"
        app:spb_progressiveStart_activated="true"
        app:spb_progressiveStart_speed="1.5"
        app:spb_progressiveStop_speed="3.4"
        app:spb_reversed="true"
        app:spb_sections_count="4"
        app:spb_speed="10.0"
        app:spb_stroke_separator_length="4dp"
        app:spb_stroke_width="4dp" />


</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/tickets_progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/progress_bar" />

<ViewStub
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/ticketsVS"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/newTicketFAB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/secondry_text"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:rippleColor="@color/divider_color"
    expandable:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post your XML layout please?

Comment: @Aaron thnak you. added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an attribute `android:backgroundTint` in your `FloatingActionButton`, and according to [View.setBackgroundTintList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)), it is only available in Android API 21 and above, which is why you are experiencing crashes on devices on lower API level. To fix the backward compatibility issue, try to replace the attribute with `app:backgroundTint`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/newTicketFAB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/secondry_text"
    app:rippleColor="@color/divider_color"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />
```